# How to input the image file from Django Admin to the html

Tags: python, html, css, django

if we don't use for, we can directly write the image address like '/img/1.jpg', but what if I already use for? what should i write? 
[image]

here is my directory of my images

[image]

here is my django/admin, which is where my image has been uploaded on django / admin
[image]

i also already add `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`

[image]

here is my html file

```
{% for product in products %}
        <section id="card">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src= '(what should i write here?)' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ product.Description }}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `src="{{ product.model_attribute_name.url }}"` assuming you have added `MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT` in settings and urls of main project.
For more information plz take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/usage/#why-do-i-get-an-error-about-importing-django-settings-module

`urls.py` file of main project should look like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I already add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in setting, but what should i write on urls of main project?

Comment: @vandettadyckies check I've updated answers in the last I've added urls for main project

Answer (score 0):

you can put your image directory inside static folder. like this

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/pics')
```

you should register static files in settings

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.staticfiles',]
```

in you template. you will use it this way

```html
<img src="/static/{{product.picture}}" class="..." alt="...">
```